# What are the advantages of using the record keyword in Java, especially for DTOs like BookRegistrationRequest? ( main text example )

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm currently using Java's record keyword for creating Data Transfer Objects (DTOs) in my application, specifically for handling POST request data.

I've chosen to use record for its conciseness and immutability, but I'm curious to learn more about the other benefits it may offer. Additionally, I'd like to know if using record in this context (as a Request DTO for POST data) is appropriate and effective.

Furthermore, are there any other use cases or scenarios where leveraging the record keyword would be particularly advantageous? I'm interested in exploring different ways to effectively utilize this feature in Java.

```
public record BookRegistrationRequest(
        String title,
        String author
) {

    public Book toDomain() {
        return new Book(title, author);
    }
}
```

```
@PostMapping
public ResponseDto<Void> registerBook(
        @RequestBody final BookRegistrationRequest bookRegistrationRequest) {
    bookFacade.registerBook(bookRegistrationRequest);
    return ResponseDto.ok();
}
```

I implemented a BookRegistrationRequest record as a DTO for handling POST requests. My expectation was that this implementation would simplify the code and provide a clear structure for data transfer.

Thank you for your insights!